# How to write a IF Formula for the Multiple IF Conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need help in writing a  formula which will be based on the following parameter:

```
          A                    B
   A1   Corporate              Formula

   B1   Distribution            Formula

   C1   DIVISION               Formula
```

I need a formula which will check the text in A column and based on the text written there it will write a "Designation" in the B Column.For Example:

If A Column contains  Corporate  then B Column will be chairman Chairman,
if DISTRIBUTION then    Chief Engineer Distribution,
if  DIVISION then   Divisional Engineer,
 If  ZONAL       then Zonal Manager
If REGION then      Superintendent Engg
If Project   then Project Manager

Kindly help.

Comment: use [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) with additional "mapping" range

Comment: Could you please help in "additional mapping range"..I didn't get that.

Comment: This type of operation is typically called a "join". See discussion here http://superuser.com/questions/420635/how-do-i-join-two-worksheets-in-excel-as-i-would-in-sql

Comment: somewhere in your workbook (maybe in hidden sheet) create range with two columns: in first colums `Corporate`, `Distribution`,.... in second columns - `chairman Chairman`, `Chief Engineer Distribution` and so on. And then use vlookup

Comment: You could also write a VBA script that would essentially look like `if , else if, else if ... ` I wouldn't put it into an Excel cell, as it gets to be a bear to edit nested `if()` statements. I think the `vlookup` is best though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, I am using a nested IF.

```
=IF(A1="Corporate", "Chairman", IF(A1="Distribution", "Chief Engineer Distribution", IF(A1="Division", "Divisional Engineer", IF(A1="ZONAL", "Zonal Manager", IF(A1="REGION", "Superintendent Engg", IF(A1="Project", "Project Manager"))))))
```

It's messy to use IF statement to do mapping. It's okay if it's a few of them but when the list grows, use what @simocco suggest.